# development of a variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I have trouble getting this result

$\begin{array}{ll}
VAR(X^2)&=VAR[(X-\theta)^2] +4\,\theta \,VAR[(X-\theta)]+4\theta\, COV[(X-\theta)^2,(X-\theta)]\\
\end{array}
$

knowing that $X$ follows the normal distribution with mean $\theta$, and variance $\theta(1-\theta)$

I write $ X^2=[(X-\theta)+\theta]^2$

$\begin{array}{ll}
X^2 &=[(X-\theta)+\theta]^2\\
 &= (X-\theta)^2+\theta^2 +2(X-\theta)\theta\\
 &= (X-\theta)^2 -\theta^2 +2\theta X\\
 &= (X-\theta)^2 +\theta(2X-\theta)
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{ll}
VAR(X^2)&=VAR[(X-\theta)^2 +\theta(2X-\theta)]\\
  &=VAR[(X-\theta)^2] +VAR[\theta(2X-\theta)]+2\, COV[(X-\theta)^2,\theta(2X-\theta)]
\end{array}
$

And I am stuck in this step.

Comment: Note that $VAR[cX] = c^2\, VAR[X]$ and $VAR[X-c]=VAR[X]$ if $c$ is  constant

Comment: so is it correct $ VAR(2X-\theta)= 4 VAR(X-\theta)$ @henry

Comment: I would have thought so, and both equal to $VAR[2X]=4\, VAR[X]$

Comment: thank you @henry